# Adjust the indentation of the items in the list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation

I want to adjust the indentation of the items in the list of figures. Right now it looks like this:

[image]

I want to move the items to the left to match the indentation of the title "List of Figures"

The only code I have used to generate this list of figures is to specify in my main.tex file the following: `\listoffigures`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tocloft`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx} % For sample figures only
\usepackage{pgffor}   % For sample figures only
\usepackage{tocloft}
\cftsetindents{fig}{0pt}{2.3em}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\chapter{Test}
\foreach \i in {1,...,5} {%
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}
        \caption{Caption 1 \i}
    \end{figure}%
}
\chapter{Test 2}
\foreach \i in {1,...,5} {%
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}
        \caption{Caption 2 \i}
    \end{figure}%
}
\end{document}
```

[image]